# How to run a project out of 2 embedded different project

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have two iOS projects and I want to make it as a single project and run one project at a time depending on a condition.

**For example** : I have 2 projects named **ProjectA** and **ProjectB**.I want to embed **ProjectA** and **ProjectB** into a single project named **ProjectC**.
**ProjectC** will have a condition depending on the condition I have to run either **projectA** or **ProjectB** code.

**Note**: Condition to run a project will be applied on runtime not on compile time.

I doubt is this really possible ? I need expertise guidance on how to approach this problem.

Comment: So ProjectC - its ios application which generate some notification which need be catched by XCode and run either projectA or ProjectB. Right? If i right could you please provide more detail why its needed? Comunication between 2 applications?

Comment: I have two different project full fledged project , and I want to integrate both the project , so that I can use the project depending on a condition .This is a requirement that I have with me.

Comment: Project A and Project B are standalone apps, correct? What is this condition? Is it determined at launch time, or is the expectation that this happen dynamically during runtime (ie. user select from a menu or changes it on the fly). The latter is more difficult.

Comment: @MobileBen, it happens in runtime.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my questions. When during runtime is important. If it is off of launch only then the approach is very different. It isn't clear to me why the current answer is upvoted so much. It really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MobileBen, Project A and Project B are standalone project , and both has a class which is starting point , let say MainViewController , depending on a response from webservice I have to launch either Project A's MainViewController or Project B's MainViewController. And from that point respective project functionality will takeover.

Comment: @MobileBen, Even I dont understand why the current answer is upvoted so much.

Comment: And once started it will stay on that project until relaunch correct? I'll provide an answer later today. I've done something similar. Similar not the same so you will probably have to iterate on the approach

Comment: @MobileBen, Yes you are right , once started it will stay on that project until relaunch .Appreciate your help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so based on reading the question and asking some questions ... it really isn't clear to me why the answer regarding pods has gotten so many votes. It does not solve the problem.

Let's say we have existing ProjectA and ProjectB. ProjectC is not yet in existence, but the desire is to make ProjectC be a "combination" of A and B where A or B will be run based on some condition. Once run, the app will stay running that version until re-launched.

Two basic approaches would be to either combine all the code and assets into ProjectC or trying to make A and B frameworks which you load. However, with either scenario, ***you are going to have make adjustments to your code base***. The amount of work you will need to do is also a byproduct of how complicated the projects are.

I've worked on a project where we successfully did what you wanted for a large app. We essentially made a "universal app" by taking our iPhone and iPad projects, combined the code/assets. We "launched" the appropriate version at runtime.

Before you go down such an effort, you will need to weigh the consequences. I'll list a few.

- If you have A/B have a dependency on bundle id, you're going to have issues. ProjectC will have it's own bundle id. For example are there any 3rd Party APIs (eg. Facebook) in use where you would want to still use them and look like ProjectA or ProjectB? If yes, but they are tied to bundle id, you'll have issues.
- If you are using IAP, your product ids will need to be different. So obviously the code in A and B will need to change if those product ids are hardcoded. If they are server driven you need to ensure the server code and actually deliver the right product ids. If there is an expectation that an owner of ProjectA should still have their IAP for ProjectC, this is possible ... however the cost comes to needing server side logic on your size to manage this.
- How much effort do you want when debugging the code?
- Are ProjectA and ProjectB still in active development? Doing this may very much make those projects very difficult to maintain afterwards.
- How much time will be set aside for this? Doing this is tedious and takes time.

You would probably get more success combining source/assets of both A and B into C. In other words **you will not** be adding the project files for A or B into C. Why? Because you need to be able to easily identify all the conflict points and then provide a work around. A simple example of a conflict is  `AppDelegate`, which is what project creates by default. You'll have 3 of them (A, B, C).

Keep in mind all approaches are fraught with issues. If you go for frameworks (regardless if they are Pods or not) and you decide your assets go into the framework bundle, you have to change your code to access them, as they are no longer in the `mainBundle`.

Okay, what are the general guidelines?

- Choose a methodology (eg. combine or framework). I am going to discuss combine.
- Determine as much of your conflicts up front. For each type of conflict determine your strategy. For example, to solve `AppDelegate` you could always do `ProjectAAppDelegate` and `ProjectBAppDelegate`.
- Examine the `Info.plist`. This is a good source of other conflicts. C's `Info.plist` will be a combination of the two.
- Come up with a strategy for how you will deal with conflicts. For example, we had a naming convention we would use when we had class names that conflicted.
- Add your ProjectA and ProjectC source code/asset into Project C. Start to fix conflicts.
- Drink a lot of coffee.

One of your other key things you will need to get control of is your entry point based on the decision. If you can decide before calling `UIApplicationMain` in `main.m`, you could do something like:

```
    Class appDelegate;

    if (runA) {
        appDelegate = [ProjectAAppDelegate class];
    } else {
        appDelegate = [ProjectBAppDelegate class];

    }

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass(appDelegate));
```

IF this does not work, then you'll have to do this in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`. You'll probably want to then have Project C's AppDelegate be a proxy for A and B. For example:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [self.projectAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:application];
}
```

where `projectAppDelegate` was set to the right version you need.

Note you will also need to manually load your storyboard to make sure the right one is launched. And keep in mind that if you spend to much time making your decision during loading (you said it was a network call) your app can be booted.

You may be able to find some nifty dynamic loading you could do if they were frameworks, but the key should be maintainability/ease of debugging.

I'm going to stop here mainly because there are so many different things to do and I really I don't have the time to write them all out.

```
Additional info based on follow up question
```

Odds are high that you will have some file duplication. I gave the example of `AppDelegate`. `enum` will be less frequent, but will occur. Also keep in mind, it is not the file name you care about, it is the class or other defined data type you are concerned about. Those are the conflicts that matter to the compiler/linker.

For example say:

ProjectA:

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, State) {}`

Project B:

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, State) {}`

This was what I meant about having a strategy ahead of time. Example strategies:

1. ProjectA is the "winner", and hence only ProjectB will have changes
2. ProjectB is the "winner", and hence only ProjectA will have changes
3. Both Project A and Project B will have changes.

So for 1, the result would be

ProjectA:

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, State) {}`

Project B:

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PBState) {}`

Note what I did hear. To make my life easier I used some pre-defined prefix to designate it is ProjectB. In this case PB.

For 2:
ProjectA:

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PAState) {}`

Project B:

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, State) {}`

For 3:
ProjectA:

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PAState) {}`

Project B:

`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PBState) {}`

It will be up to you to make the rules, but be consistent.
You will need a strategy for how you will resolve all the data type changes. For example, if you are going from `State` -> `PBState`, you obviously only want to modify ProjectB. Here is where having it in it's own project would help. However, you can use Xcode's `Search Scope` to help control this.

Oh some other things.

Up front, invest on a script to find all the duplicate files in ProjectA and ProjectB. You basically need to do a `find` on ProjectA and ProjectB based on the extensions you need (eg. .m, .h, .xib, etc). This will give you a list of potential candidates and from there you can strategize on rules.

As I was the sucker that did this part of the project, I basically kept this list in a text file. When I consolidated the file, I moved it to a different section (separated by several newlines) in the file. There are diff ways of doing the accounting on it, it is simply the method I chose.

I would also make sure you have a good diff tool like Araxis Merge (which is what I used).

Also, take frequent snapshots just in case. You can use git branching. I often just copied the actual directories so I could diff them later if needed.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts to give a detailed answer to my questions.I will follow the guidelines that you have laid out above.I must say this answer gave me good clarification on my query .I just have one more clarification , did u come across issues with enum and file duplication when the Project A and Project B has same file name or enum structure.Can you give your suggestion on how to handle that part.

Comment: @karthik I added some more info in the answer. Hopefully that answers it. I suggest you discuss the caveats with your team so everyone understands the risks.

Comment: This answer is not just extensive, but also the correct one. I have no idea how the pods answer got so many upvotes either, it's just not addressing the issue. Well done, @karthik. You should get the bounty.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest that you create pods and call your project, you can call it based on scenario/use-case, like this you can keep any number of projects in your pods.

You can refer this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift).

Another way is to keep your two projects in same path, create dynamic frameworks and use those references into project 'C' I mean the new project which you are planning for

Any one of the approach should solve your problem.

Comment: As per my knowledge cocoa pods is used as dependency manager , which can be used to download and link a third party framework and I am not sure how this can solve my problem .can you please elaborate your answer with atleast one approach.